# margin / padding not applied correctly

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML & CSS code. Here's an image of the problem I have: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njFIb.png).

I don't know why top-padding there is 10px - it should be 20px.

I've tried to adjust the margins & padding of various elements but none seem to adjust the problem. Does anybody know what is causing this and how it can be fixed?

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,900'; /* font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; */

html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; background: #ffffff; }

img { width: 100%; display: block; }

.block { color: #fff; font-size: 18px; background: #444444; text-align: center; padding: 10px 0px; } /* padding inside col */

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrap { width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; background: transparent; padding: 10px;} /* padding surrounding grid */

.grid { width: 100%; }

.grid:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }

.row { padding: 0px 0; background: transparent; }

.col-1-4 { width: 25%; }
.col-1-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-3-4 { width: 75%; }
.col-1-1 { width: 100%; }

.col-1-5 { width: 20%; }

[class*='col'] { float: left; padding: 10px; } /* padding between cols & rows */

.gallery-grid { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 100%; }
.gallery-grid li { position: relative; float: left; overflow: hidden; width: 16.6666667%; width: -webkit-calc(100% / 6); width: calc(100% / 6); }

@media (max-width: 768px) { [class*='grid'] { width: 100%; } [class*='col'] { width: 100%; padding: 10px 20px;} }
@media (max-width: 768px) { .gallery-grid li { width: 33.3333333%; width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3); width: calc(100% / 3); } }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
 
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/siimple.css">
 
</head>

<body>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><div class="block">1-2</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><div class="block">1-2</div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <ul class="gallery-grid">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-1"><div class="block">1-1</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And why it should be 20px? Where is the rule for that?

Comment: Could you pls regenerate the issue and put a jsfiddle with only specific portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update this

```
.col-1-1 { width: 100%; padding-top: 20px !important; }
```

in your code there is a padding of 10px around the cols, so between 2 cols there is a padding of 20px in total.

or set the rule for .col-1-1 below your col* rule. then its without !important.

Answer (score 0):

try adding clear:both style after every row

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,900'; /* font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; */

html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; background: #ffffff; }

img { width: 100%; display: block; }

.block { color: #fff; font-size: 18px; background: #444444; text-align: center; padding: 10px 0px; } /* padding inside col */

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrap { width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; background: transparent; padding: 10px;} /* padding surrounding grid */

.grid { width: 100%; }

.grid:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }

.row { padding: 0px 0; background: transparent; }

.col-1-4 { width: 25%; }
.col-1-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-3-4 { width: 75%; }
.col-1-1 { width: 100%; }

.col-1-5 { width: 20%; }

[class*='col'] { float: left; padding: 10px; } /* padding between cols & rows */

.gallery-grid { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 100%; }
.gallery-grid li { position: relative; float: left; overflow: hidden; width: 16.6666667%; width: -webkit-calc(100% / 6); width: calc(100% / 6); }

@media (max-width: 768px) { [class*='grid'] { width: 100%; } [class*='col'] { width: 100%; padding: 10px 20px;} }
@media (max-width: 768px) { .gallery-grid li { width: 33.3333333%; width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3); width: calc(100% / 3); } }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
 
<head>

    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/siimple.css">
 
</head>

<body>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-4"><div class="block">1-4</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><div class="block">1-2</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-2"><div class="block">1-2</div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <ul class="gallery-grid">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x800"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-1"><div class="block">1-1</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
    <div class="col-1-5"><div class="block">1-5</div></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, on the second last line, the media query says that the padding should be:

```
padding: 10px 20px;
```

Read: **"Padding top-bottom = 10px, while left-right = 20px"**

Replace this with the following, if you want 20px on the top.

```
padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
```

You should also update the code on the 7th last line:

```
[class*='col'] { float: left; padding: 10px; }

/* It should be the following - modify at will */
[class*='col'] { float: left; padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px; }
```

#### Suggestion for the fufture of your CSS career

In future, if something like this happens again, the devtools for your browser can be a godsend in debugging CSS problems. In chrome (and firefox and I think IE) you can right-click and choose 'inspect'. If you want to learn more, look up a tutorial on how to use your browser's devtools.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, in your css, gallery-grid element is larger than the element containing it, i.e, "row". So it is flowing outside the container.

To fix this, theres a clearfix hack :-

Just add a `.clearfix` class to all the rows and define it as:

```
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This will fix the issue.